# trying to upgrade old java jsf application

Tags: java, mysql, jsf

Sorry first time i am posting anything....  I am trying to upgrade an old Java/JSF application to tomcat 8, JSF 1.2 and JDK 1.6.  I am getting interactive errors on the dataconverter.

Here is the error when trying to save: [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X2bUw.png)

`#{currentRow.value['horseledger.DATE']}' Cannot convert [3/31/19 12:00 AM] of type [class java.util.Date] to [class java.sql.Date]`

Here is the JSF code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jsp:root version="2.1" xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core" xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html" xmlns:jsp="http://java.sun.com/JSP/Page" xmlns:webuijsf="http://www.sun.com/webui/webuijsf">
    <jsp:directive.page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8"/>
    <f:view>
        <webuijsf:page id="page1">
            <webuijsf:html id="html1">
                <webuijsf:head id="head1">
                    <webuijsf:link id="link1" url="/resources/stylesheet.css"/>
                </webuijsf:head>
                <webuijsf:body id="body1" style="-rave-layout: grid">
                    <webuijsf:form binding="#{PartnerTrans.form1}" id="form1" virtualFormsConfig="partner | partnerDD | partnerDD , statement | statementDD | statementDD , save | table1:tableRowGroup1:tableColumn2:dropDown1 table1:tableRowGroup1:tableColumn5:textField3 table1:tableRowGroup1:tableColumn6:textField4 table1:tableRowGroup1:tableColumn3:textField1 table1:tableRowGroup1:tableColumn4:textField2 | savebtn , add/delete | | table1:tableRowGroup1:tableColumn7:button1 addbtn">
                        <div style="position: absolute; left: 48px; top: 0px">
                            <jsp:directive.include file="header.jspf"/>
                        </div>
                        <webuijsf:label id="label1" labelLevel="1" style="position: absolute; left: 48px; top: 120px" text="Partner:"/>
                        <webuijsf:label id="label2" labelLevel="1" style="position: absolute; left: 48px; top: 144px" text="Statement:"/>
                        <webuijsf:table augmentTitle="false" id="table1" style="position: absolute; left: 48px; top: 216px" title="Transactions" width="560">
                            <webuijsf:tableRowGroup binding="#{PartnerTrans.tableRowGroup1}" id="tableRowGroup1" rows="10"
                                sourceData="#{PartnerTrans.partnerledgerDataProvider}" sourceVar="currentRow">
                                <webuijsf:tableColumn headerText="Transaction" id="tableColumn2">
                                    <webuijsf:dropDown converter="#{PartnerTrans.dropDown1Converter}" id="dropDown1"
                                        items="#{PartnerTrans.partnertranstypeDataProvider.options['transtype.TRANSTYPE,transtype.TRANSDESC']}" selected="#{currentRow.value['partnerledger.TRANSTYPE']}"/>
                                    <webuijsf:message for="dropDown1" id="message1" showDetail="false" showSummary="true"/>
                                </webuijsf:tableColumn>
                                <webuijsf:tableColumn headerText="Units" id="tableColumn3" sort="partnerledger.UNITS">
                                    <webuijsf:textField id="textField1" text="#{currentRow.value['partnerledger.UNITS']}"/>
                                    <webuijsf:message for="textField1" id="message2" showDetail="false" showSummary="true"/>
                                </webuijsf:tableColumn>
                                <webuijsf:tableColumn headerText="Unit Price" id="tableColumn4" sort="partnerledger.UNITPRICE">
                                    <webuijsf:textField id="textField2" text="#{currentRow.value['partnerledger.UNITPRICE']}"/>
                                    <webuijsf:message for="textField2" id="message3" showDetail="false" showSummary="true"/>
                                </webuijsf:tableColumn>
                                <webuijsf:tableColumn headerText="Total" id="tableColumn1" width="20">
                                    <webuijsf:staticText converter="#{PartnerTrans.numberConverter1}" id="staticText1" text="#{currentRow.value['partnerledger.UNITS'] * currentRow.value['partnerledger.UNITPRICE']}"/>
                                </webuijsf:tableColumn>
                                <webuijsf:tableColumn headerText="Date" id="tableColumn5" sort="partnerledger.DATE">
                                    <webuijsf:textField converter="#{PartnerTrans.dateTimeConverter1}" id="textField3" text="#{currentRow.value['partnerledger.DATE']}"/>
                                    <webuijsf:message for="textField3" id="message4" showDetail="false" showSummary="true"/>
                                </webuijsf:tableColumn>
                                <webuijsf:tableColumn headerText="Notes" id="tableColumn6" sort="partnerledger.NOTES">
                                    <webuijsf:textField id="textField4" text="#{currentRow.value['partnerledger.NOTES']}"/>
                                    <webuijsf:message for="textField4" id="message5" showDetail="false" showSummary="true"/>
                                </webuijsf:tableColumn>
                                <webuijsf:tableColumn headerText="Delete" id="tableColumn7">
                                    <webuijsf:button actionExpression="#{PartnerTrans.button1_action}" id="button1" text="Delete"/>
                                </webuijsf:tableColumn>
                            </webuijsf:tableRowGroup>
                        </webuijsf:table>
                        <webuijsf:button actionExpression="#{PartnerTrans.addbtn_action}" id="addbtn"
                            style="left: 72px; top: 192px; position: absolute; width: 150px" text="Add Transaction"/>
                        <webuijsf:button actionExpression="#{PartnerTrans.savebtn_action}" id="savebtn"
                            style="left: 240px; top: 192px; position: absolute; width: 150px" text="Save Changes"/>
                        <webuijsf:button actionExpression="#{PartnerTrans.returnbtn_action}" id="returnbtn"
                            style="left: 408px; top: 192px; position: absolute; width: 150px" text="Return to Menu"/>
                        <webuijsf:staticText id="staticText2" style="position: absolute; left: 432px; top: 144px" text="Statement Total:"/>
                        <webuijsf:staticText binding="#{PartnerTrans.totalstxt}" converter="#{PartnerTrans.numberConverter1}" id="totalstxt" style="position: absolute; left: 528px; top: 144px"/>
                        <webuijsf:messageGroup id="messageGroup1" style="left: 624px; top: 144px; position: absolute"/>
                        <webuijsf:dropDown binding="#{PartnerTrans.statementDD}" converter="#{PartnerTrans.bigDecimalConverter1}" id="statementDD"
                            items="#{PartnerTrans.statementdatesDataProvider.options['statementdates.STATEMENTID,statementdates.STATEDESC']}"
                            onChange="webui.suntheme.common.timeoutSubmitForm(this.form, 'statementDD');" style="position: absolute; left: 144px; top: 144px" valueChangeListenerExpression="#{PartnerTrans.statementDD_processValueChange}"/>
                        <webuijsf:dropDown binding="#{PartnerTrans.partnerDD}" converter="#{PartnerTrans.bigDecimalConverter2}" id="partnerDD"
                            items="#{PartnerTrans.partnersDataProvider.options['partners.PARTNERID,partners.PARTNERNAME']}"
                            onChange="webui.suntheme.common.timeoutSubmitForm(this.form, 'partnerDD');" style="position: absolute; left: 144px; top: 120px" valueChangeListenerExpression="#{PartnerTrans.partnerDD_processValueChange}"/>
                    </webuijsf:form>
                </webuijsf:body>
            </webuijsf:html>
        </webuijsf:page>
    </f:view>
</jsp:root>
```

here is the java code:

```
/*
 * PartnerTrans.java
 *
 * Created on July 10, 2007, 12:12 AM
 * Copyright ketnera
 */
package renpheracctv5;

import com.sun.data.provider.RowKey;
import com.sun.data.provider.impl.CachedRowSetDataProvider;
import com.sun.rave.web.ui.appbase.AbstractPageBean;
import com.sun.webui.jsf.component.Body;
import com.sun.webui.jsf.component.Button;
import com.sun.webui.jsf.component.DropDown;
import com.sun.webui.jsf.component.Form;
import com.sun.webui.jsf.component.Head;
import com.sun.webui.jsf.component.Html;
import com.sun.webui.jsf.component.Label;
import com.sun.webui.jsf.component.Link;
import com.sun.webui.jsf.component.Message;
import com.sun.webui.jsf.component.MessageGroup;
import com.sun.webui.jsf.component.Page;
import com.sun.webui.jsf.component.StaticText;
import com.sun.webui.jsf.component.Table;
import com.sun.webui.jsf.component.TableColumn;
import com.sun.webui.jsf.component.TableRowGroup;
import com.sun.webui.jsf.component.TextField;
import com.sun.webui.jsf.model.SingleSelectOptionsList;
import java.math.BigDecimal;
import javax.faces.FacesException;
import javax.faces.convert.BigDecimalConverter;
import javax.faces.convert.DateTimeConverter;
import javax.faces.convert.NumberConverter;
import javax.faces.event.ValueChangeEvent;

/**
 * <p>Page bean that corresponds to a similarly named JSP page.  This
 * class contains component definitions (and initialization code) for
 * all components that you have defined on this page, as well as
 * lifecycle methods and event handlers where you may add behavior
 * to respond to incoming events.</p>
 */
public class PartnerTrans extends AbstractPageBean {
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Managed Component Definition">
    private int __placeholder;

    /**
     * <p>Automatically managed component initialization.  <strong>WARNING:</strong>
     * This method is automatically generated, so any user-specified code inserted
     * here is subject to being replaced.</p>
     */
    private void _init() throws Exception {
        statementdatesDataProvider.setCachedRowSet((javax.sql.rowset.CachedRowSet)getValue("#{SessionBean1.statementdatesRowSet}"));
        partnersDataProvider.setCachedRowSet((javax.sql.rowset.CachedRowSet)getValue("#{SessionBean1.partnersRowSet}"));
        partnerledgerDataProvider.setCachedRowSet((javax.sql.rowset.CachedRowSet)getValue("#{SessionBean1.partnerledgerRowSet}"));
        partnertranstypeDataProvider.setCachedRowSet((javax.sql.rowset.CachedRowSet)getValue("#{SessionBean1.partnertranstypeRowSet}"));
        dateTimeConverter1.setTimeZone(null);
        dateTimeConverter1.setPattern("MM/dd/yyyy");
        numberConverter1.setMinIntegerDigits(1);
        numberConverter1.setMaxIntegerDigits(40);
        numberConverter1.setMaxFractionDigits(3);
        numberConverter1.setType("currency");
        numberConverter1.setCurrencySymbol("$");
    }

    private Form form1 = new Form();

    public Form getForm1() {
        return form1;
    }

    public void setForm1(Form f) {
        this.form1 = f;
    }

    private CachedRowSetDataProvider statementdatesDataProvider = new CachedRowSetDataProvider();

    public CachedRowSetDataProvider getStatementdatesDataProvider() {
        return statementdatesDataProvider;
    }

    public void setStatementdatesDataProvider(CachedRowSetDataProvider crsdp) {
        this.statementdatesDataProvider = crsdp;
    }

    private BigDecimalConverter statementDDConverter = new BigDecimalConverter();

    public BigDecimalConverter getStatementDDConverter() {
        return statementDDConverter;
    }

    public void setStatementDDConverter(BigDecimalConverter bdc) {
        this.statementDDConverter = bdc;
    }

    private CachedRowSetDataProvider partnersDataProvider = new CachedRowSetDataProvider();

    public CachedRowSetDataProvider getPartnersDataProvider() {
        return partnersDataProvider;
    }

    public void setPartnersDataProvider(CachedRowSetDataProvider crsdp) {
        this.partnersDataProvider = crsdp;
    }

    private BigDecimalConverter partnerDDConverter = new BigDecimalConverter();

    public BigDecimalConverter getPartnerDDConverter() {
        return partnerDDConverter;
    }

    public void setPartnerDDConverter(BigDecimalConverter bdc) {
        this.partnerDDConverter = bdc;
    }

    private TableRowGroup tableRowGroup1 = new TableRowGroup();

    public TableRowGroup getTableRowGroup1() {
        return tableRowGroup1;
    }

    public void setTableRowGroup1(TableRowGroup trg) {
        this.tableRowGroup1 = trg;
    }

    private CachedRowSetDataProvider partnerledgerDataProvider = new CachedRowSetDataProvider();

    public CachedRowSetDataProvider getPartnerledgerDataProvider() {
        return partnerledgerDataProvider;
    }

    public void setPartnerledgerDataProvider(CachedRowSetDataProvider crsdp) {
        this.partnerledgerDataProvider = crsdp;
    }

    private CachedRowSetDataProvider partnertranstypeDataProvider = new CachedRowSetDataProvider();

    public CachedRowSetDataProvider getPartnertranstypeDataProvider() {
        return partnertranstypeDataProvider;
    }

    public void setPartnertranstypeDataProvider(CachedRowSetDataProvider crsdp) {
        this.partnertranstypeDataProvider = crsdp;
    }

    private BigDecimalConverter dropDown1Converter = new BigDecimalConverter();

    public BigDecimalConverter getDropDown1Converter() {
        return dropDown1Converter;
    }

    public void setDropDown1Converter(BigDecimalConverter bdc) {
        this.dropDown1Converter = bdc;
    }

    private DateTimeConverter dateTimeConverter1 = new DateTimeConverter();

    public DateTimeConverter getDateTimeConverter1() {
        return dateTimeConverter1;
    }

    public void setDateTimeConverter1(DateTimeConverter dtc) {
        this.dateTimeConverter1 = dtc;
    }

    private StaticText totalstxt = new StaticText();

    public StaticText getTotalstxt() {
        return totalstxt;
    }

    public void setTotalstxt(StaticText st) {
        this.totalstxt = st;
    }

    private NumberConverter numberConverter1 = new NumberConverter();

    public NumberConverter getNumberConverter1() {
        return numberConverter1;
    }

    public void setNumberConverter1(NumberConverter nc) {
        this.numberConverter1 = nc;
    }
    private DropDown statementDD = new DropDown();

    public DropDown getStatementDD() {
        return statementDD;
    }

    public void setStatementDD(DropDown dd) {
        this.statementDD = dd;
    }
    private BigDecimalConverter bigDecimalConverter1 = new BigDecimalConverter();

    public BigDecimalConverter getBigDecimalConverter1() {
        return bigDecimalConverter1;
    }

    public void setBigDecimalConverter1(BigDecimalConverter bdc) {
        this.bigDecimalConverter1 = bdc;
    }
    private DropDown partnerDD = new DropDown();

    public DropDown getPartnerDD() {
        return partnerDD;
    }

    public void setPartnerDD(DropDown dd) {
        this.partnerDD = dd;
    }
    private BigDecimalConverter bigDecimalConverter2 = new BigDecimalConverter();

    public BigDecimalConverter getBigDecimalConverter2() {
        return bigDecimalConverter2;
    }

    public void setBigDecimalConverter2(BigDecimalConverter bdc) {
        this.bigDecimalConverter2 = bdc;
    }

    // </editor-fold>

    /**
     * <p>Construct a new Page bean instance.</p>
     */
    public PartnerTrans() {
    }

    /**
     * <p>Callback method that is called whenever a page is navigated to,
     * either directly via a URL, or indirectly via page navigation.
     * Customize this method to acquire resources that will be needed
     * for event handlers and lifecycle methods, whether or not this
     * page is performing post back processing.</p>
     *
     * <p>Note that, if the current request is a postback, the property
     * values of the components do <strong>not</strong> represent any
     * values submitted with this request.  Instead, they represent the
     * property values that were saved for this view when it was rendered.</p>
     */
    public boolean add;
    public void init() {
        // Perform initializations inherited from our superclass
        super.init();
        // Perform application initialization that must complete
        // *before* managed components are initialized
        // TODO - add your own initialiation code here

        // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Managed Component Initialization">
        // Initialize automatically managed components
        // *Note* - this logic should NOT be modified
        try {
            _init();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log("PartnerTrans Initialization Failure", e);
            throw e instanceof FacesException ? (FacesException) e: new FacesException(e);
        }

        // </editor-fold>
        // Perform application initialization that must complete
        // *after* managed components are initialized
        // TODO - add your own initialization code here
    }

    /**
     * <p>Callback method that is called after the component tree has been
     * restored, but before any event processing takes place.  This method
     * will <strong>only</strong> be called on a postback request that
     * is processing a form submit.  Customize this method to allocate
     * resources that will be required in your event handlers.</p>
     */
    public void preprocess() {
    }

    /**
     * <p>Callback method that is called just before rendering takes place.
     * This method will <strong>only</strong> be called for the page that
     * will actually be rendered (and not, for example, on a page that
     * handled a postback and then navigated to a different page).  Customize
     * this method to allocate resources that will be required for rendering
     * this page.</p>
     */
    public void prerender() {
        if (partnerDD.getSelected() == null) {
            Object firstPartnerId = null;
            Object firstStatementId = null;
            try {
                partnersDataProvider.cursorFirst();
                firstPartnerId = partnersDataProvider.getValue("partners.PARTNERID");
                partnerDD.setSelected(firstPartnerId);
                statementdatesDataProvider.cursorFirst();
                firstStatementId = statementdatesDataProvider.getValue("statementdates.STATEMENTID");
                statementDD.setSelected(firstStatementId);
                getSessionBean1().getPartnerledgerRowSet().setObject(1, firstPartnerId);
                getSessionBean1().getPartnerledgerRowSet().setObject(2, firstStatementId);
                partnerledgerDataProvider.refresh();

            } catch (Exception e) {
                log("Error Description", e);
                error(e.getMessage());
            }
        }
        try {
            if (add == false){
                BigDecimal totalValue = new BigDecimal("0.0");

                partnerledgerDataProvider.cursorFirst();
                int rows = partnerledgerDataProvider.getRowCount();
                for (int i=0; i < rows; i++){
                    BigDecimal value = (BigDecimal) partnerledgerDataProvider.getValue("partnerledger.UNITS");
                    BigDecimal price = (BigDecimal) partnerledgerDataProvider.getValue("partnerledger.UNITPRICE");
                    value = value.multiply(price);
                    if (value != null){
                        totalValue = totalValue.add(value);
                    }
                    partnerledgerDataProvider.cursorNext();
                }
                totalstxt.setValue(totalValue);
            } else {
                add = false;
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            log("Error Description", e);
            error(e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    /**
     * <p>Callback method that is called after rendering is completed for
     * this request, if <code>init()</code> was called (regardless of whether
     * or not this was the page that was actually rendered).  Customize this
     * method to release resources acquired in the <code>init()</code>,
     * <code>preprocess()</code>, or <code>prerender()</code> methods (or
     * acquired during execution of an event handler).</p>
     */
    public void destroy() {
        statementdatesDataProvider.close();
        partnersDataProvider.close();
        partnerledgerDataProvider.close();
        partnertranstypeDataProvider.close();
    }

    /**
     * <p>Return a reference to the scoped data bean.</p>
     */
    protected ApplicationBean1 getApplicationBean1() {
        return (ApplicationBean1)getBean("ApplicationBean1");
    }

    /**
     * <p>Return a reference to the scoped data bean.</p>
     */
    protected RequestBean1 getRequestBean1() {
        return (RequestBean1)getBean("RequestBean1");
    }

    /**
     * <p>Return a reference to the scoped data bean.</p>
     */
    protected SessionBean1 getSessionBean1() {
        return (SessionBean1)getBean("SessionBean1");
    }

    public void partnerDD_processValueChange(ValueChangeEvent event) {
        Object selectedpartner = partnerDD.getSelected();
        Object selectedStatement = statementDD.getSelected();

        try {
            partnersDataProvider.setCursorRow(partnersDataProvider.findFirst("partners.PARTNERID", selectedpartner));
            statementdatesDataProvider.setCursorRow(statementdatesDataProvider.findFirst("statementdates.STATEMENTID", selectedStatement));

            getSessionBean1().getPartnerledgerRowSet().setObject(1, selectedpartner);
            getSessionBean1().getPartnerledgerRowSet().setObject(2, selectedStatement);
            partnerledgerDataProvider.refresh();
            form1.discardSubmittedValues("save");

        } catch (Exception e) {
            log("Error Description", e);
            error(e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    public void statementDD_processValueChange(ValueChangeEvent event) {
        //        ledgerTbl.setVisible(true);
        Object selectedStatement = statementDD.getSelected();
        Object selectedPartner = partnerDD.getSelected();

        try {
            statementdatesDataProvider.setCursorRow(statementdatesDataProvider.findFirst("statementdates.STATEMENTID", selectedStatement));

            getSessionBean1().getPartnerledgerRowSet().setObject(1, selectedPartner);
            getSessionBean1().getPartnerledgerRowSet().setObject(2, selectedStatement);
            partnerledgerDataProvider.refresh();
            form1.discardSubmittedValues("save");

        } catch (Exception e) {
            log("Error Description", e);
            error(e.getMessage());
        }

    }

    public String addbtn_action() {
        try {
            RowKey rk = partnerledgerDataProvider.appendRow();
            partnerledgerDataProvider.setCursorRow(rk);

            partnerledgerDataProvider.setValue("partnerledger.PARTNERID", partnerDD.getSelected());
            partnerledgerDataProvider.setValue("partnerledger.TRANSTYPE", new BigDecimal(1));
            partnerledgerDataProvider.setValue("partnerledger.STATEMENTID", statementDD.getSelected());
            partnerledgerDataProvider.setValue("partnerledger.UNITS", new BigDecimal(0.0));
            partnerledgerDataProvider.setValue("partnerledger.UNITPRICE", new BigDecimal(0.0));

            add = true;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log("Error Description", e);
            error(e.getMessage());
        }

        return null;
    }

    public String savebtn_action() {
        try {
            partnerledgerDataProvider.commitChanges();
            partnerledgerDataProvider.refresh();
        } catch (Exception e){
            log("Error Description", e);
            error(e.getMessage());
        }

        return null;
    }

    public String button1_action() {
        form1.discardSubmittedValues("save");
        try {
            RowKey rk = tableRowGroup1.getRowKey();
            if (rk != null) {
                partnerledgerDataProvider.removeRow(rk);
                partnerledgerDataProvider.commitChanges();
                partnerledgerDataProvider.refresh();}
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            log("Error Description", ex);
            error(ex.getMessage());
        }

        return null;
    }

    public String returnbtn_action() {
        // TODO: Process the action. Return value is a navigation
        // case name where null will return to the same page.
        return "case1";
    }
}
```

Rowsets from session bean

```
        partnersRowSet.setDataSourceName("java:comp/env/jdbc/renpherdbv2_MYSQL");
        partnersRowSet.setCommand("SELECT ALL partners.`PARTNERID`, partners.`PARTNERNAME`, partners.`ADDRESS1`, partners.`ADDRESS2`, partners.`CITY`, partners.`STATE`, partners.`ZIP`, partners.`EMAIL`, partners.`TAXID`, partners.`CELLPHONE`, partners.`ALTPHONE`  FROM partners ORDER BY partners.`PARTNERNAME` ASC");
        partnersRowSet.setTableName("partners");
        statementdatesRowSet.setDataSourceName("java:comp/env/jdbc/renpherdbv2_MYSQL");
        statementdatesRowSet.setCommand("SELECT * FROM statementdates");
        statementdatesRowSet.setTableName("statementdates");
        partnerledgerRowSet.setDataSourceName("java:comp/env/jdbc/renpherdbv2_MYSQL");
        partnerledgerRowSet.setCommand("SELECT ALL partnerledger.PARTNERID, \n                    partnerledger.TRANSTYPE, \n                    partnerledger.UNITS, \n                    partnerledger.UNITPRICE, \n                    partnerledger.DATE, \n                    partnerledger.NOTES, \n                    partnerledger.STATEMENTID, \n                    partnerledger.TRANSID \nFROM partnerledger\nWHERE partnerledger.PARTNERID = ?\n          AND partnerledger.STATEMENTID = ? ");
        partnerledgerRowSet.setTableName("partnerledger");
        partnertranstypeRowSet.setDataSourceName("java:comp/env/jdbc/renpherdbv2_MYSQL");
        partnertranstypeRowSet.setCommand("SELECT ALL transtype.TRANSTYPE, \n                    transtype.TRANSDESC, \n                    transtype.HORSEPARTNER \nFROM transtype\nWHERE transtype.HORSEPARTNER = 'P' ");
        partnertranstypeRowSet.setTableName("transtype");
```

The database is MySql with a type of DATE for the field.  Here is the table DDL:

```
CREATE TABLE `partnerledger` (
  `PARTNERID` decimal(7,0) DEFAULT NULL,
  `TRANSTYPE` decimal(7,0) DEFAULT NULL,
  `UNITS` decimal(8,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `UNITPRICE` decimal(10,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `DATE` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `NOTES` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `STATEMENTID` decimal(7,0) DEFAULT NULL,
  `TRANSID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  PRIMARY KEY (`TRANSID`),
  KEY `PARTNERID` (`PARTNERID`),
  KEY `STATEMENTID` (`STATEMENTID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=11569 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
CREATE TABLE `statementdates` (
  `STATEMENTID` decimal(7,0) NOT NULL,
  `STATEDESC` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `STARTDATE` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `ENDDATE` date DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`STATEMENTID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1

CREATE TABLE `transtype` (
  `TRANSTYPE` decimal(7,0) NOT NULL,
  `TRANSDESC` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  `HORSEPARTNER` char(1) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`TRANSTYPE`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1

CREATE TABLE `partners` (
  `PARTNERID` decimal(7,0) NOT NULL,
  `PARTNERNAME` varchar(35) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ADDRESS1` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ADDRESS2` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  `CITY` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  `STATE` varchar(2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ZIP` decimal(9,0) DEFAULT NULL,
  `EMAIL` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `TAXID` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `CELLPHONE` varchar(15) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ALTPHONE` varchar(15) DEFAULT NULL,
  `USERNAME` varchar(15) DEFAULT NULL,
  `PASSWORD` varchar(15) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ACTIVE` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  PRIMARY KEY (`PARTNERID`),
  KEY `PARTNERNAME` (`PARTNERNAME`),
  KEY `ACTIVE` (`ACTIVE`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

There are no errors in the tomcat logs.

I feel like it might be a class issue since there are no imports of java.util.date or java.sql.date in the whole project.  Maybe a mysql connector.  Using mysql-connector-java-5.1.47.jar

As an update also this is happening for all dates in the application, so I am guessing its a jdbc or mysql connector issue, but not sure how to fix.

Comment: The "relevant java" code in your question is incomplete, and makes no sense as it stands. Please address that.

Comment: Yes, make a [mcve] and read [ask]  and more... ypu need to improve you question immensly.

Comment: The error message is recognizable as the one coming from JDBC not from JSF. Please post the stack trace to prove otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

Created a custom converter that converted the java.util.date to a java.sql.date.  I am going to work on adding the ability to handle different formats shortly but did this to get the application working!  Code is below:

```
public class CustSQLDateConverter implements Converter
{
    private String dateFormat = new String();

     public void SetDateFormat (String df)
     {
         dateFormat = df;
     }


    @Override
     public Object getAsObject(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, 
            String value)
    {
        SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat(dateFormat);
        Date parsed = null;
        try {
            parsed = format.parse(value);

        } catch(ParseException pe)
        {
            pe.printStackTrace();
        }
        java.sql.Date sql = new java.sql.Date(parsed.getTime());  
        return (sql);

    }

    public String getAsString(FacesContext context, UIComponent component,
            Object value)
    {
        String dtstring = value.toString();
        String[] dt = dtstring.split("-");
        String fmtDate = dt[1] + "/" + dt[2] + "/" + dt[0];
        return fmtDate;
    }
}
```

Comment: Better to change it in the location where you get it back from the database. Not the best solution (bad even imo).... The application should **nowhere** use java.sql.date

Comment: I agree.  I am not writing this application from scratch or it would be designed way different.  It was written over 10 years ago and i don't think touched since.  On top of that it looks like they used a code generator or something from netbeans.  I agree its not the best solution but it was the easiest band aid on an old application to get it working.